# Preloader for shockwave in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, preloader, shockwave

I found out a cool way to preload a flash in this page http://www.riacodes.com/flash/basic-flash-preloader/

But is a preloader for a flash to another flash without having to modify the other flash

The code would be like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.load(new URLRequest("content.swf"));

function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var ratio:Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal;
    percent.text = Math.ceil(ratio*100).toString();
    bar.scaleX = ratio;

}

function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
    removeChild(percent);
    removeChild(bar);
    percent = null;
    bar = null;
    addChild(loader);
}
```

But I would like to make a few (or several changes to use it with a shockwave), is there any simple way or would it better to implement something with cs3 and javascript?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash Player cannot load content designed for Shockwave Player.